# Some doubts about gallery shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I'm using Jetpack with Wordpress and creating a gallery. The thing is that I don't want all the images from that gallery to be shown, only the last 50 of them. Is there any solution to this using just the shortcode?

If not, is there any other solution?

Also, I have another doubt about the usage of galleries in Wordpress, is it possible to assign a name (or ID) to the gallery and call it in the code? For example

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[gallery name='my_gallery']"); ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the *attached* image gallery, from another post, you can use:

```
[gallery id="123"]
```

where the custom `id` attribute is the post ID.

If you want limit the number of items in a gallery, there seems to be a plugin available on wordpress.org called [Limit parameter for gallery shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-parameter-for-gallery-shortcode/) (no affiliation). It uses the `pre_get_posts` filter to change the `posts_per_page` and `offset` attributes of the `get_posts()` or `get_children()` calls in the gallery shortcode callback.

Example:

```
[gallery id="4" limit="3" offset="1"]
```

Comment: This seems perfect. Also, is there any attribute to put in the shortcode for displaying a fixed number of images? For example, for just displaying the last 10 images

Comment: Please check out the updated the answer @Bizcochoman