# Gallery Shortcode - only show first x thumbnails

Tags: gallery

Is there a way to only show the first 6 thumbnails on the actual post but when a user clicks on any of the thumbnails, then he can browse all images in the post gallery?

Essentially, I would like the exact functionality of this code but with only showing the first 6 thumbnails instead of all of them:

```
[gallery link="file"]
```

Comment: Check out the [Codex on the Gallery Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode). You can use attachment IDs to only grab 6 images.

Comment: But how do I know the attachment IDs automatically for each gallery ?

Comment: Could this help anyone? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries

Comment: I don't quite understand the context. If you're using the Media Module ( pop up ) you can select 6 images and it will generate the shortcode for you. Are you trying to get a specific post / page gallery, then get the first 6 images of that gallery?

Comment: I am looking for a custom shortcode that will automatically show the first 6 thumbnails on the actual post instead of all the thumbnails.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the situation. In said post you have attached images to it, and you want to show 6 of these images as a post gallery at the bottom of the post? Or, does the post already have a gallery somewhere at the top and you want to show only 6 of the post gallery at the bottom of the post? Could you edit your original question and tell us where the images are in the post?

Comment: ok edited. hope this is clear?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176930/some-doubts-about-gallery-shortcode-in-wordpress/176937#176937) will help?

Comment: From the dev: Note that this plugin is a little bit of a hack. Also from my understanding it will not display all the images when you click on the thumbnails..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know this is a bit of cheating but if I use this code essentially I achieve what I want, albeit the thumbnails are loaded on the page unnecessarily..

```
<div style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
[gallery columns="4" link="file"] 
</div>
```